# Casting a JSON column value as DateTime

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to cast a json column key to DateTime?

For example I have a value json column

```
{ 
    'date_to': 'March 30 2020', 
    'date_from': 'March 20 2020'
}, 
{
    'date_to': 'April 30 2020', 
    'date_from': 'April 20 2020'
}
```

Answers model

```
class Answers extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts = [
        'value' => 'Array',
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) instead of casts and iterate over the array and cast each key's value to date time.

```
// in Answers model

public function getValueAttribute($value)
{
    $array = json_decode($value, true);

    return collect($array)->map(function ($sub_array) {
       return collect($sub_array)->map(function ($item) {
           return Carbon::parse($item)->toDateTimeString();
       });
    })->toArray();
}
```